# Transitive closure proof (Pierce, ex. 2.2.7)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Simple exercise taken from the book **Types and Programming Languages** by Benjamin C. Pierce.

This is a definition of the transitive closure of a relation R.

First, we define the sequence of sets of pairs:

$$R_0    = R$$
$$R_{i+1}  = R_i \cup \{ (s, u) | \exists t, (s, t) \in R_i, (t, u) \in R_i \}$$
Finally, define the relation $R^+$ as the union of all the $R_i$:
$$R^+=\bigcup_i R_i$$
Show that $R^+$ is really the transitive closure of R.

Questions:

1. I would like to see the proof (I don't have enough mathematical background to make it myself).
2. Isn't the final union superfluous? Won't $R_n$ be the union of all previous sequences?

Comment: How do you define the transitive closure?

Comment: @AsafKaragila According to the book: *Transitive closure* of **R** is the smalles transitive relation **R'** that contains **R**.

Comment: @Maxym: A proof is available at [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Recursive_Construction_of_Transitive_Closure).

Comment: @Lord_Farin thanks, didn't know how to find it.

Comment: Still, question number 2: why do we need the final union?

Comment: @Maxym, its true that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $R_n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n R_i$. But the final union is not superfluous, because $R^+$ is essentially the same as $R_\infty$, and we never get to infinity.

Comment: @Maxym: I answered the second question in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, if this is how you **define** the transitive closure, then the proof is over. But you may still want to see that it is a transitive relation, and that it is contained in any other transitive relation extending $R$.

To the second question, the answer is simple, no the last union is not superfluous because it is infinite. Every step contains *a bit more*, but not necessarily *all* the needed information.

So let us see that $R^+$ is really transitive, contains $R$ and is contained in any other transitive relation extending $R$.

1. Clearly $R\subseteq R^+$ because $R=R_0$.
2. If $x,y,z$ are such that $x\mathrel{R^+} y$ and $y\mathrel{R^+}z$ then there is some $n$ such that $x\mathrel{R_n}y$ and $y\mathrel{R_n}z$, therefore in $R_{n+1}$ we add the pair $(x,z)$ and so $x\mathrel{R_{n+1}}z$ and therefore $x\mathrel{R^+}z$ as wanted.
3. If $T$ is a transitive relation containing $R$, then one can show it contains $R_n$ for all $n$, and therefore their union $R^+$. To see that $R_n\subseteq T$ note that $R_0$ is such; and if $R_n\subseteq T$ and $(x,z)\in R_{n+1}$ then there is some $y$ such that $(x,y)\in R_n$ and $(y,z)\in R_n$. Since $R_n\subseteq T$ these pairs are in $T$, and since $T$ is transitive $(x,z)\in T$ as well.

Comment: About the second question - so in the other words - we just don't know what is n, And if we have infinite union that we don't need to know what is n, right?

Comment: @Maxym: To show that the infinite union is necessary, you can consider $\mathcal R$ defined on $\Bbb N$ by putting $m \mathrel{\mathcal R} n$ iff $n = m+1$.

Answer (score 4):

We need to show that $R^+$ contains $R$, is transitive, and is minmal among all such relations.

$R\subseteq R^+$ is clear from $R=R_0\subseteq \bigcup R_i=R^+$.

Transitivity:
By induction on $j$, show that $R_i\subseteq R_j$ if $i\le j$.
Assume $(a,b), (b,c)\in R^+$. Then $(a,b)\in R_i$ for some $i$ and $(b,c)\in R_j$ for some $j$. This implies $(a,b),(b,c)\in R_{\max(i,j)}$ and hence $(a,c)\in R_{\max(i,j)+1}\subseteq R^+$.

Now for minimality, let $R'$ be transitive and containing $R$.
By induction show that $R_i\subseteq R'$ for all $i$, hence $R^+\subseteq R'$, as was to be shown.

As for your specific question #2:
Yes, $R_n$ contains all previous $R_k$ (a fact, the proof above uses as intermediate result). But neither is $R_n$ merely the union of all previous $R_k$, nor does there necessarily exist a *single* $n$ that already equals $R^+$.
For example, on $\mathbb N$ take the realtaion $aRb\iff a=b+1$. Then $aR^+b\iff a>b$, but $aR_nb$ implies that additionally $a\le b+2^n$.